# how to make sure that a variable always refers to the same range (not the same address) in a google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to assign a range to a variable and later set some of its cells even if in the meantime its address has been changed due to some row/column insertion/deletion.

In the following snippet the strings are written to the same row even if I need to write to two different rows, the one created first and the one created second.

```
function addingRows() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
var r1=sheet.getRange("1:1")
sheet.insertRowBefore(1);
// now r1 continue to refer to the first row even if it has became the second one!
var r2=sheet.getRange("1:1")
// I want to write on the second row (the first row that shifted one row below due to the row insertion) 
// but the following line writes to the first row!
r1.getCell(1,1).setValue("first created row")
// the following line writes to the first row as expected
r2.getCell(1,2).setValue("second created row")
}
```

In other words, I want to write "first created row" in the previously-first row that became the second one after the row insertion, but it seems that variable `r1` points to the first row even after the row insertion.

How to do it?

Comment: Please explain using an example what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I commented my code. Hope it helps to understand my question.

Comment: That's because r1 refers to a range not values.  1:1 is still row one even if you shift the value down one row with the insertRow.  You could use r1.offset(numberofinserts,0) by keeping track of the number of inserts in another variable.

Comment: This is similar to an answer from this post: [How to get actual position of range, when new row(s) above was added](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52777954/15384825).

Comment: @irvin Thank you for your hint. That's about my very same problem. Since it appears that here I have described it poorly, I will delete my question. (will your upvoted comment retain the vote?)

Answer (score 0):

```
function addingRows() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const r1 = sh.getRange("1:1")
  let n = 0;
  sh.insertRowBefore(1);
  n++;
  const r2 = sh.getRange("1:1")
  r1.getCell(n + 1, 1).setValue("first created row")
}
```